# Azure Active Directory Console: TrustedForDelegation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management

I am using the Set-MsolServicePrincipal to update the TrustedForDelegation flag:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194110.aspx

I have tried several different commands:

Set-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId $AppId -TrustedForDelegation true

Where $AppId is a valid App Principal Id. However, no matter what combination of "TrustedForDelegation" flag I use, the console throws up the following error:

Set-MsolServicePrincipal : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
name 'TrustedForDelegation'.
At line:1 char:49
+ Set-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId $AppId -TrustedForDelegation true
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolServicePrincipal],
    ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administ
   ration.Automation.SetServicePrincipal

What is the correct flag to use to update "TrustedForDelegation"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this? This is an internal (to Microsoft) parameter that doesn't really provide any useful features (that I can think of).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you link to and the error message, there is no TrustedForDelegation parameters in the AAD PowerShell cmdlets.

(Note: Although this parameter doesn't exist, you would normally want to set a PowerShell boolean with `$true`, not `true`.)